# Android support design library vs. raygun

Tags: android, android-design-library, raygun

I have an app that uses Raygun. This is giving me problems when I try to update the com.android.support:design library. They works fine when I use com.android.support:design:22.2.0, but when I go up to com.android.support:design:23.+ I get a series of errors akin to this:

{Path}\raygun4android-1.3.0-sources.jar(main/java/com/mindscapehq/android/raygun4android/RaygunClient.java):15: error: package org.apache.http does not exist

I get that same error for api's 15-19.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `org.apache.http` legacy jar to the applicaiton

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, now I'm getting the message, "Unable to find optional library: 'org.apache.http.legacy"